# How to change BitmapEffect in custom WPF control via C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapeffect

I have a custom control type like: `<Grid> ... </Grid>` and Grid.BitmapEffect property. How can I change BitmapEffetc in this Control (Grid) via C# code (e.g. on event)?

Code sample - part of custom control:

```
[...]
<Grid Background="#FFE5AA">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>            
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.BitmapEffect>
        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="#459E5A" GlowSize="13" Noise="0" Opacity="0.9" />
    </Grid.BitmapEffect>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="#F5B903" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" >
    </Border>
[...]
```

Then in Window.xaml:

```
<controls:MyControl Name="Control1" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Control1_MouseDown" />
```

Then in C#:

```
private void Control1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //there i want to change Control1.BitmapEffect
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've got it! I was add an DepencyProperty 'GlowSize' and simply change size of glow via it. :) Works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

```
myGrid.BitmapEffect = null;
```

PS: Note that [BitmapEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.bitmapeffect.aspx) is considered obsolete and that [Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.effect.aspx) should be used instead.

---

Here's an example based on your sample which works perfectly fine (here on my machine): As soon as I click within the Grid, the effect disappears.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCsApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<Grid Background="#FFE5AA" Margin="10" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.BitmapEffect>
        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="#459E5A" GlowSize="13" Noise="0" Opacity="0.9" />
    </Grid.BitmapEffect>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="#F5B903" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" >
        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        myGrid.BitmapEffect = null;
    }
}
```

---

In your example you write: `//there i want to change Control1.BitmapEffect`. Note that you need to change the BitmapEffect of the *Grid*, not the BitmapEffect of *Control1*.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine. Can you provide a short example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Your sample working for me too. But it not woeking in my app :|
Btw. can You add an effect in C# code? I need glow grid onClick and disable glow in other grids, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Different effects are listed here : [Different BitmapEffect](http://dotnetnews.fr/apercu-classe-bitmapeffect-wpf)